# Bash script match grep output and send message

Tags: bash, scripting, monit

I am developing a script for monit status checking so I can send OK status messages to NagiOS NSCA server (passive checks). The problem I am having is that my bash script still sends messages if the scripts grep function does not include anything that would trigger the message sending.

Script:

Variables

```
rsysl='rsyslog'
log='messages'
```

Commands in variables

```
host=$(hostname)
monstat=$(monit status|grep -C 1 '$rsysl')
nsca_status=$(echo -e "$host\t$rsysl\t0\tOK" | /usr/sbin/send_nsca -H mon.lv.lan -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg)
```

Monit status command

```
# Postfix check
$monstat
```

Message sending function as you can see it only should send the message when **status** is equal to **not running** and **not accessible**

```
if [ "status" == "not running" ] && [ "status" == "not accessible" ]; then
   $nsca_status
else
   :
fi
```

Grep output (in real situation the message sending command has to match **running** and **accessible**:

```
# monit status|grep -C 1 'rsyslog'

Process 'rsyslog'
  status                            Running
--

File 'rsyslog-messages-log'
  status                            Accessible
```

Comment: could you please share your final version how you combine monit and nsca?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually a number of problems in the excerpts you posted. The one that's making it always send messages is that the "Commands in variables" section isn't doing what you think it's doing. Specifically, what `var=$(command)` does is *execute the command immediately*, then put its *output* in the variable. Since the `nsca_status=$( ... | /usr/sbin/send_nsca ... )` command is always executed, the message is always sent -- and sent before the `if` statement that's supposed to decide whether to send it or not.

In general, storing a command in a variable is tricky (see [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)), and generally a bad idea. In a case like this, either just use the command directly (without trying to store and retrieve it), or use a function:

```
nsca_status() {
    echo -e "$host\t$rsysl\t0\tOK" | /usr/sbin/send_nsca -H mon.lv.lan -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg
}
```

(and then execute it with just `nsca_status` -- no `$`.)

In the case of the other two commands in that section, you probably actually do want to execute them immediately and store the results, so they're mostly OK. Well, actually, there is a problem with `monstat=$(monit status|grep -C 1 '$rsysl')` -- the single-quotes around `$rsysl` will prevent it from being expanded as a variable reference, so `grep` will be searching for `$rsysl`, instead of `rsyslog`. To fix this, use double-quotes instead. Variable references should almost always be wrapped in double-quotes. But note that you should *not* then try to execute `$monstat` as a command -- that'll try to execute `grep`'s output (`Process 'rsyslog' status Running ...`) as if it were a command, which makes no sense.

The other problems I see are in the `if` statement:

```
if [ "status" == "not running" ] && [ "status" == "not accessible" ]; then
```

...there are actually 3 fatal problems here (and one minor quibble): first, it's comparing the *string* "status" with "not running" and "not accessible", but you want to be comparing the output of the `monit status | grep ...` command. This is simple to fix, use `"$monstat"` instead of `"status"`.

Second, the `&&` part means it'll trigger only if *both* matches occur; that is, if something's not running *and* something's not accessible. I would expect you'd want to trigger the report if *either* something's not running *or* something's not accessible, so use `||` instead.

Third, you're doing string equality tests; that is, you're checking to see if the entire report consists of "not running", and *nothing else*. I'm pretty sure you want to see if it *contains* "not running" or "not accessible". You can do this with bash's more advanced conditional expression (`[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`), which allows wildcard matches:

```
if [[ "$monstat" = *"not running"* ]] || [[ "$monstat" = *"not accessible"* ]]; then
```

... where the wildcards (`*`) match whatever's before & after the string in question. BTW, note that I also used `=` instead of `==` -- it's actually more standard in shell scripts. Another option would be to use `grep` to do the matching:

```
if echo "$monstat" | grep -E -q "not running|not accessible"; then
```

note that there are no `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` here; the `if` statement looks at whether the command succeeded or failed, and `grep` succeeds only if it finds a match. The `-q` part tells `grep` not to print whatever match it finds -- we don't want to see the match, just to know whether there was one.

Actually, it occurs to me that there might be a fourth serious problem: does `monit status` capitalize its status messages? This is important because "Not running" (or "Not Running") will not match "not running". If it's capitalized, either capitalize the search string the same way, or do a case-insentive search with either `[[ "$monstat" = *[nN]"ot "[rR]"unning"* ]]` or grep's `-i` option.

Oh, and a final note: if you don't need an `else` clause, just leave it out. No need to have an empty one with the `:` pseudo-command.

Anyway, with all these changes here's what I get for the entire script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
rsysl='rsyslog'
log='messages'

# Function to send a status message
nsca_status() {
    echo -e "$host\t$rsysl\t0\tOK" | /usr/sbin/send_nsca -H mon.lv.lan -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg
}

# Store output of commands
host=$(hostname)
monstat=$(monit status|grep -C 1 '$rsysl')

# Send message if there's anything wrong
if [[ "$monstat" = *[nN]"ot "[rR]"unning"* ]] || [[ "$monstat" = *[nN]"ot "[aA]"ccessible"* ]]; then
    nsca_status
fi
```

EDIT: I think I may've misunderstood the sense of the test; is it supposed to send the data if everything is OK? I was assuming it was sending an error status, and hence should send only if there was a problem. If that's the case, use appropriate `!`'s to invert the sense of the matches. In the `[[ ]]` version, use `!=` to see if the string is *not* found:

```
if [[ "$monstat" != *[nN]"ot "[rR]"unning"* ]] && [[ "$monstat" != *[nN]"ot "[aA]"ccessible"* ]]; then
```

In the grep version, a single `!` inverts the entire `if` test:

```
if ! echo "$monstat" | grep -E -i -q "not running|not accessible"; then
```

Comment: Thank you for a awesome answer. Tried your fixes, but it does not work still. Would the problem be in the monit status command? I have heard that a command that has spaces in it, wont run in variable. Maybe I should change monit status command to function?

Comment: And I do need both Not running and Not accessible match. If either one of them is ok I do not need to send OK status.

Comment: The monit status is working fine, but the if statement does not seems to send the data to NSCA. I am fustrated over this :S

Comment: @mYzk: I think I misunderstood when it should send the data -- see edit.

Comment: I got it fixed already, but thanks :) It helped me a lot